# Activity used in 2 different ways, only allow one instance of each

Tags: android

I have QueueActivity that can be accessed on its own, and also a SearchActivity that can launch a QueueActivity intent with search results.  I want to make it so that one of each of these two types of QueueActivity can be launched but no more than one of each.  How can I go about doing this?

I tried using `ActivityManager` to see what instances are already running but I can only get Tasks, not individual Activities.  I tried using `Intent.FLAG_REORDER_TO_FRONT` but of course that will only allow one total QueueActivity, not two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to have one instance of your `Activity` than you just have to set the `launchMode` to `singleInstance` in your manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activities.SomeActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:theme="@style/SomeTheme" />
```

Comment: What if I want the old instance to be stopped and a new instance created every time I launch an Activity?  So that I always have a single instance but it always launches a new instance?

Comment: Why would you want that? It seems to me you are having trouble understanding or dealing with the `Activity` life cycle.

Comment: Because I'm sending it new data every time I'm launching it.  I guess I can handle the data in onResume instead of onCreate then?

Comment: Yes exactly, load data in `onResume()`. Restarting an `Activity` is already bad, but to do it just to update its content would be terrible.